# Errors in Salesforce CMS post sandbox refresh

Tags: salesforce-cms

Did anyone encountered this as well? When sandbox is refreshed, the media contents in salesforce CMS are corrupted. However when we try to delete it, we are seeing this error. Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Are you able to access the entity starting with 05T... shown in the error message?See http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-01403 about the exception.  Please log a case with Salesforce Support providing this stack trace and ask to delete the dangling references.Thanks

Comment: Hey @Swetha We can't access unfortunately. I guess logging a case is the way to go! thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @drm . I have posted this information as an answer so others facing the same issue might find it helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message, [ORA-01403](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-01403) code refers to "No data found". Also the ID of  entity specified in error is the starting with 05T which is ContentBody as per http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html

As confirmed in the comments section, this entity is not accessible as there seem to be [dangling references](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/what-is-dangling-reference) causing the deletion to fail.

The solution would be to log a Salesforce Support case to have these dangling references fixed.